# how can I maximize the GPU usage of Tensorflow 2.0 from R (with Keras library)?

Tags: r, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I use R with Keras and tensorflow 2.0 on the GPU.

After connecting a second monitor to my GPU, I receive this error during a deep learning script:

[image]

I concluded that the GPU is short of memory and a solution seems to be this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # dynamically grow the memory used on the GPU
config.log_device_placement = True  # to log device placement (on which device the operation ran)
                                    # (nothing gets printed in Jupyter, only if you run it standalone)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)  # set this TensorFlow session as the default session for Keras
```

According to this post:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7072#issuecomment-422488354

Although this code is not accepted by R.
It says

> unexpecterd token from Tensorflow.
>
> Error in tf.ConfigProto() : could not find function "tf.ConfigProto"

It seems that tensorflow 2.0 does not accept this code if I understand correct from this post:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33504

Does anyone know how I can maximize the GPU usage from my R script with Keras library and Tensorflow 2.0 ?

Thank you!

Comment: @ Axeman That is great! It returns PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'). When I use  tf$config$experimental$set_memory_growth(device = 0, enable = TRUE) it says Unrecognized device: 0.0

Comment: @ Axeman Thanks a lot!! This is the solution!

Comment: @ Axeman elegant solution to solve it by gpu <- tf$config$experimental$get_visible_devices('GPU')[[1]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable GPU memory growth using `keras` or `tensorflow` in R, with `tensorflow` 2.0, you need to find the correct functions in the `tf` object.

First, find your GPU device:

```
library(tensorflow)
gpu <- tf$config$experimental$get_visible_devices('GPU')[[1]]
```

Then enable memory growth for that device:

```
tf$config$experimental$set_memory_growth(device = gpu, enable = TRUE)
```

You can find more relevant functions by typing `tf$config$experimental$` and then using tab autocomplete in Rstudio.

Since these functions are labeled as experimental, they will likely change or move location in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!